# Umbraco 8, 0 How to authenticate front-end member login via AD (ADLTS)

Tags: authentication, active-directory, membership-provider, umbraco8

We have an Umbraco site running on Umbraco 8.6.3 (upgraded from v7) local installation, not cloud. The site is set up with Group based protection.

We need to authenticate Umbraco Members against our own AD-LTS (not Azure)
(preferable with a fallback to standard Umbraco membership authentication if member is not found in AD but does exist in Umbraco).

Can anyone share with me some example code or reference for this that works in V8 (8.6.3)?

Answer (score 0):

I have setup Umbraco 8 to use Active Directory login by following this excellent post by Shannon Deminick. It might not be exactly what you need but should be a starting point

https://shazwazza.com/post/configuring-azure-active-directory-login-with-umbraco/